# How to automate addition of pass phrase in fttplib in python

Tags: python, ssl, curl, ftp, ftps

I am trying to download files using ftps. I'm using ftplib in python. The issue is that on trying to establish connection, I always have to manually enter the passphrase for the key. How can I automate this ?

This curl command is working perfectly

```
curl -k -la --ftp-method nocwd --ftp-ssl -u test_user:test_password --key my_key.key --cert my_cert.crt:cert_password ftp.mysite.com
```

But when I'm trying with python, I have to manually enter "cert_password"

```
import ftplib
conn = ftplib.FTP_TLS(host='ftp.mysite.come', user='test_user', passwd='test_password', keyfile='my_key.key', certfile='my_cert.crt')
```

Comment: What? Manually enter it where?

Comment: In my python shell, as soon as I enter "conn = ftplib.FTP_TLS...", I get a prompt for entering the passphrase. On entering "cert_password" and hitting enter the connection is established.

Comment: Do you need it in the shell? Could you just write it in a script and run that as needed?

Comment: I wrote a script too but either way, I've to enter the passphrase to continue further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't work with *ftplib*, but according to [[Python]: *class* ftplib.**FTP_TLS**(*host='', user='', passwd='', acct='', keyfile=None, certfile=None, context=None, timeout=None, source_address=None*)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP_TLS):

> *keyfile* and *certfile* are a legacy alternative to *context* – they can point to PEM-formatted private key and certificate chain files (respectively) for the SSL connection.

Looking at [[Python]: SSL Contexts](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl-contexts), you should do the connection in 2 steps:

```
import ssl
import ftplib
ctx = ssl.SSLContext()
ctx.load_cert_chain("my_cert.crt", keyfile="my_key.key", password="cert_password")
conn = ftplib.FTP_TLS(host="ftp.mysite.come", user="test_user", passwd="test_password", context=ctx)
```

Comment: Thanks. Turns out I have been checking an outdated documentation.